# Side of headphone doesn't work unless I hold the volume button or pause/play button on headphone.

Tags: headphones

I have a pair of Samsung headphones with a mic, volume control, and pause/play button. I have used these headphones for over a year. They worked perfectly. Then one day, the right side decided to quit on me. The right side of the headphone is the one with the little control box. The left side plays sound perfectly fine. When I hold the volume button or pause/play button the right side turns on and I can hear out of both sides. There is no problem with the cord, just the right side.

Comment: Welcome to ee.se. Please read the [help] to understand the sort of question answered here. This site is intended for electronic design question, and not repair,so it is likely to get closed.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like there may be a bad connection within the control button box.  When pressing the button(s), the pressure re-establishes the connection.

Comment: Which means, if you can pop the control box open with a small screwdriver, you may be able to find it and solder it back together again, then re-glue the box. This carries some risk of destroying the headphones in the process, however.